# JSF 2.3 whole bean validation throws all fields away. Is it intended? Do I use something wrong?

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation, jsf-2.3

I have a form with lets say 3 fields:

- password hint
- password
- password again

I have a bean, which contains these 3 fields, and I have a class level validator, which checks if the bean has a matching `password` and `password again` field. Imagine a pretty similar setup, like it is at https://github.com/AnghelLeonard/JSF-2.3/tree/master/JSF23ValidateWholeBeanExample

The problem which I face, that I enter a `password hint`, a `password` and a non matching `password again`. This case I get the whole form cleared, since as it seems to me, the WholeBeanValidator prevents JSF from saving any value into the model. The relevant code place is in [com.sun.faces.ext.component.WholeBeanValidator.validate(FacesContext, UIValidateWholeBean, Object)](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/2_3/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/ext/component/WholeBeanValidator.java#L143):

```
// Mark the components as invalid to prevent them from receiving
// values during updateModelValues
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> validationCandidateEntry : validationCandidate.entrySet()) {
    invalidateComponent(validationCandidateEntry);
}

throw toThrow;
```

This case I think it would be good to keep the model values in the fields and to get the global error message. However the values do not come into the bean. Do I understand something wrong? Could you help me in this @BalusC :)?

Comment: Since it does not seem easy to solve this problem I could apply Springs @Validated annotation on the service methods as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The Section [What's new in JSF 2.3? - Class level bean validation](https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1) on Arjan Tijms' Weblog cites:

> In JSF the idea is that the model is not touched if validation fails.

This suggests that what you describe as a problem indeed works as intended.

If using ajax, maybe you should limit updating to messages and (if using primefaces) labels instead of updating the entire form including input fields.